# Crop nodata from a spatial image

Tags: python, numpy, gdal

I have several rasters where the pixel information is elevation data. However, there are a lot of nodata values (zero's) in the image that exist beyond the extent of the data I want, so the file sizes are unnecessarily large. I have tried to crop the image using a mix of gdal and numpy but I have noticed a small sub-pixel sized shift in the image. Is this a rounding error, and can anything be done to solve this?

Its not very pythonic in places but seems to work ok except for the small shift

I'm also open to any alternative methods to do this with python/numpy/gdal...

My code is:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import os
import subprocess

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)

inDir = '/path/to/files'
outDir = '/path/for/outfiles'

files = [file for file in os.listdir(inDir) if file.endswith('.tif')]

for file in files:
    outfile= os.path.join(outDir, file)
    if os.path.isfile(outfile):
        print('File exists')
        pass
    else:
        try:
            print(file)

            # open raster and read in the data
            dataset = gdal.Open(file)
            band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
            Cols = dataset.RasterXSize
            Rows = dataset.RasterYSize
            print('Reading Radar data...')
            data = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, Cols, Rows).astype(np.float)
            # Read in the projection onfo
            ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

            # define the corner co-ords
            ulx = ulx
            uly = uly
            lrx = ulx + (dataset.RasterXSize * xres)
            lry = uly + (dataset.RasterYSize * yres)


            # Make two arrays with the co-ords for each pixel
            XP = np.arange(ulx, lrx, xres, dtype=np.float64)
            YP = np.arange(uly, lry, yres, dtype=np.float64)            

            # Make an array the same shape as data populated with the X dimensions
            print('Building X dimensions...')
            Xarr = np.zeros_like(data)
            Xarr[...] = XP

            # Make an array the same shape as data populated with the Y dimensions
            print('Building Y dimensions...')
            Yarr = np.zeros_like(data)
            Yarr = Yarr.transpose()
            Yarr[...] = YP
            Yarr = Yarr.transpose()

            # Mask out the X and Y co-ords arrays based on presence of valid data
            print('Subsetting data...')
            SubXarr = Xarr[data > 0]
            SubYarr = Yarr[data > 0]
            SubData = data[data > 0]

            #Get the bounding co-ords based on presence of valid data
            # note yres is -ve
            print('Finding corner coords...')
            Xmin = np.amin(SubXarr)
            Xmax = np.amax(SubXarr) + abs(xres)
            Ymin = np.amin(SubYarr) - abs(yres)
            Ymax = np.amax(SubYarr)

            print(Xmin, Ymin)
            print(Xmax, Ymax)

            # Subset the input image based on the bounding co-ords
            outfile = os.path.join(outDir, file)
            print('Cropping Data to ' + str(outfile.split('/')[-1]))

            subprocess.call('gdalwarp -of GTiff -r cubic -tr ' + str(xres) + ' ' + str(yres) + ' -te ' + str(Xmin) + ' ' + str(Ymin) + ' ' + str(Xmax) + ' ' + str(Ymax) + ' -tr ' + str(xres) + ' ' + str(yres) + ' ' + str(file) + ' ' + str(outfile),shell=True)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('Could not process: ', str(outfile.split('/')[-1]))
```

Comment: If there is a coordinate system associated with the final product, the shift is probably 1/2 a pixel width in size and is due to whether the center of the cell or the edge of the cell is associated with the defining coordinates

Comment: @NaN I did consider this but I think its the corner of the pixel and not the center. the shift is very small (less than half a pixel) so I assumed it was a rounding error on the resolution

Comment: I suspect the issue is from specifying the -te target extents with insufficient precision. How are Xmin and Ymin integer multiples of xres and yres from the original ulx uly?